# Flutter: Keep firebase user logged in forever until manual log out

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I use firebase authentication in my flutter app. When I test it in the android emulator, the user is logged out once I re-deploy the app over the IDE. On a real device the user gets logged out after a few hours. How can I prevent that? I saw that some people store the user credentials (e-mail & password) in the shared preferences, but this seems not to be the way to go, especially regarding security. This is my code:

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<User?> get authStateChanges => _auth.authStateChanges();

  Future<AuthResult> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      if (_auth.currentUser == null) {
        final userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        print('User is signed in');
        return AuthResult(success: true, message: 'User is signed in');
      } else {
        print('User is already signed in');
        return AuthResult(success: true, message: 'User is already signed in');
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print('User is not signed in $e');
      return AuthResult(success: false, message: mapErrorCodeToMessage(e.code));
    }
  }
}
```

main

```
   // Use StreamBuilder to listen for auth changes. If auth is null, show sign-in widget.
   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: authService.authStateChanges,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              return ThemeBuilder(
                authService: authService,
                themeModeNotifier: themeModeNotifier,
                child: MyHomePage(
                  title: 'My Homepage',
                  firestore: Firestore(snapshot.data!.uid),
                  authService: authService,
                  themeModeNotifier: themeModeNotifier,
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return MaterialAppProvider(home: SignInPage(authService: authService), themeMode: themeModeNotifier.value,);
            }
          },
        );
      }
...
```

Comment: User don't get automatically signed out under normal circumstances using the Firebase Auth cloud service.  You should use the auth state observer to find out when a user is definitely signed in or signed out.  It can take some time for the observer to report that fact (the user will initially appear signed out, but that is not true).  The emulator is different in that when you kill and restart the emulator, the token that it issued previously is no longer valid, and you have to sign in again.

Comment: "On a real device the user gets logged out after a few hours." That should not happen. When you sign in with Firebase, the SDK persists the necessary information locally and (as Doug also said) then tried to restore that information when the app restarts/page reloads. --- Can you describe/show how you determined that the user gets logged out after a few hours?